# MySqli let user edit single record

Tags: php, html, mysqli

learner here, going a little nuts..
i seem to be getting no errors, yet it is not updating.
connection is fine.

```
if(isset($_GET['edit_id'])){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM info WHERE id=" .$_GET['edit_id'];
    $result= mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}


//update
if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $suname=$_POST['surname'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $result=$_POST['result'];
    $log=$_POST['log'];

    $update="UPDATE employeeinfo SET name='$name', surname='$surname' WHERE id=". $_GET['edit_id'];
    $up= mysqli_query($connect, $update);

    if(!isset($sql)){
        die("Error $sql" .mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: record.php");
    }
}
```

and my calling

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>edit info<h1>
<form method="post">
name:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><br><br>
surname: <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" value="<?php echo $row['surname']; ?>"><br><br>

log: <input type="text" name="log" placeholder="0" value="<?php echo $row['log']; ?>"><br><br>

<button type"submit" name"btn-update" id="btn-update" onclick="update()"><strong>Update</strong></button>

<a href="record.php"><button type="button" value="button">Cancel</button></a>
</form>


<script>
function update(){
    var x;
    if(confirm("Updated data Successfully") == true){
        x = "update";
    }

}

</script>
```

Not even sure if that script does anything, because my prompt said "update successful" yet clearly it wasnt. Thank you guys as always

Comment: i tried using other code and changing it to fit my needs, should my $up be used instead of $update somewhere?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Your form does not have an action, is the PHP code in the same file?

Comment: You forgot to put `=` signs in two places, it should be `<button type="submit" name="btn-update" ...`

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you again sir, SQL injections will be my next part of my education, as im still testing my basic practices!!

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Thank you so much, you're the man! As usual, i feel very silly -.- sometimes when you look at the big picture you cant focus on the small. Thanks again!!

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Guys, another problem. im only testing the name and surname update for the moment. the name update works great... the Surname is being deleted (or replaced by an empty space) every time i update the record.. im using <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" value="<?php echo $row['surname']; ?>">

Comment: @JayBlanchard anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Charlesx54321 Simple, you missed a `r` in `$suname=$_POST['surname'];`, it should be `$surname=$_POST['surname'];`. Turn on error reporting, add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your PHP scripts.